# Show line / separator view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to show a separator line in my SwiftUI app. To achieve that, I tried to create an empty view with a fixed frame and a background color / border:

```swift
EmptyView()
    .frame(width: 200, height: 2)
    .background(Color.black) // or:
    .border(Color.black, width: 2)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot see any dark view showing up.
Is there a way to show a separator / line view?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use the build-in [Divider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/divider) `View`:

> A visual element that can be used to separate other content.

Example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Divider()
            Text("Hello Another World")
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Ah! I tried `Separator`, `Line`, but didn't think of `Divider`. Thanks!

Comment: how do you get rid of this mysterious padding below and above the line?

Comment: @coolcool1994 Set the `spacing` of the VStack to zero. I.e. `VStack(spacing: 0) {…}`

Answer (score 92):

If anyone is interested a divider, text, divider, looking like this:

[image]

## `LabelledDivider` code

```swift
struct LabelledDivider: View {

    let label: String
    let horizontalPadding: CGFloat
    let color: Color

    init(label: String, horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 20, color: Color = .gray) {
        self.label = label
        self.horizontalPadding = horizontalPadding
        self.color = color
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            line
            Text(label).foregroundColor(color)
            line
        }
    }

    var line: some View {
        VStack { Divider().background(color) }.padding(horizontalPadding)
    }
}
```

It's kind of ugly but I had to put the `Divider`s into a `VStack` to make them horizontal, otherwise, they will be vertical, due to `HStack`. Please let me know if you managed to simplify this :)

Also maybe using and stored properties for `LabelledDivider` might not be the most `SwiftUI`-y solution, so I'm open to improvements.

## Example usage

This is the code that results in the screenshot seen above:

```swift
struct GetStartedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                NavigationLink(destination: SignInView()) {
                    Text("Sign In").buttonStyleEmerald()
                }

                LabelledDivider(label: "or")

                NavigationLink(destination: SignUpView()) {
                    Text("Sign up").buttonStyleSaphire()
                }

            }.padding(20)
        }
    }
}
```

## ButtonStyle

For sake of completness, I also include `buttonStyle` view modifiers:

```swift
struct ButtonStyle: ViewModifier {

    private let color: Color
    private let enabled: () -> Bool
    init(color: Color, enabled: @escaping () -> Bool = { true }) {
        self.color = color
        self.enabled = enabled
    }

    dynamic func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(enabled() ? color : Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}

extension View {
    dynamic func buttonStyleEmerald(enabled: @escaping () -> Bool = { true }) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: ButtonStyle(color: Color.emerald, enabled: enabled))
    }

    dynamic func buttonStyleSaphire(enabled: @escaping () -> Bool = { true }) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: ButtonStyle(color: Color.saphire, enabled: enabled))
    }

}
```

Edit: Please note that `Color.saphire` and `Color.emerald` are custom declared colors:

```swift
extension Color {
    static var emerald:     Color { .rgb(036, 180, 126) }
    static var forest:      Color { .rgb(062, 207, 142) }
}

extension Color {
    static func rgb(_ red: UInt8, _ green: UInt8, _ blue: UInt8) -> Color {
        func value(_ raw: UInt8) -> Double {
            return Double(raw)/Double(255)
        }
        return Color(
            red: value(red),
            green: value(green),
            blue: value(blue)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Color.Radix.emerald`?

Comment: Just some color I have declared... feel free to replace with your own :)

Comment: @Sajjon I know this is late but you can remove the init and just define the label in the view constructor in similar fashion to if you used the init. Just removed a layer of complexity.

Comment: I use very similar code to this and had to add `.lineLimit(1).fixedSize()` to prevent line-breaks and ellipses for longer translations

Comment: Inherit color separator light and dark theme, color: Color = Color(UIColor.separator)

Answer (score 37):

You can just draw a line by using Color. If you want to change the line width or padding, you can use `frame` or `padding` like other SwiftUI Components.

```
//Horizontal Line in VStack
VStack{
    Color.gray.frame(height: 1 / UIScreen.main.scale)
}
//Vertical Line in HStack
HStack{
    Color.gray.frame(width: 1 / UIScreen.main.scale)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Nice tips. I never knew to create a frame based on colour. Thanks

Comment: Smart and concise.

Comment: Very elegant, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a way to customize the divider, there isn't any. You must provide your custom implementation:

```swift
struct CustomDivider: View {
    let height: CGFloat = 1
    let color: Color = .white
    let opacity: Double = 0.2
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Rectangle()
        }
        .frame(height: height)
        .foregroundColor(color)
        .opacity(opacity)
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution works well, but why do you use *Group* here? It seems to work without it

Answer (score 2):

`Divider` can't have a height or color I guess, instead you can use the below code:

```
Rectangle()
    .frame(height: 1)
    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant of response @Sajjon

Fixeds:

- Default UI Color separator for divisor
- Truncate text
- correct spacing
- line ajusting into center of text

```swift
struct LabelledDivider: View {

    let label: String
    let horizontalPadding: CGFloat
    let color: Color

    init(label: String, horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 8, color: Color = Color(UIColor.separator)) {
        self.label = label
        self.horizontalPadding = horizontalPadding
        self.color = color
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            line
            Text(label)
                .font(.callout)
                .foregroundColor(color)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .fixedSize()
                .offset(y: -1)
            line
        }
    }

    var line: some View {
        VStack() { Divider().frame(height: 1).background(color) }.padding(horizontalPadding)
    }
}

struct PositionSampleView: View {
    var body: some View {

        LabelledDivider(label: "or")

        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
HStack {
    VStack {
        Divider()
    }
    Text("or")
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
    VStack {
        Divider()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why answering a topic which is already done 3 years ago!?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?