# draw lines on all rows of a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, layout, uitextview

I want to draw a line in UITextView to separate lines like a notebook.

After researching, I came across the following [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585980/draw-lines-on-uitextview-and-align-the-text-accordingly), but the information was out of date and could not be applied to the current version.

Is it possible to draw lines on the UITextView?

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56619112/2253720

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a `UITextView` subclass and override `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`.

Here is an example that should get you on your way:

```
class LinedTextView: UITextView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        // this is needed to tell the lines to redraw
        //  when the text is scrolled
        self.contentMode = .redraw
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
              let font = self.font
        else {
            super.draw(rect)
            return
        }
        
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(1.0)
        context.beginPath()
        
        let nLines = (self.contentSize.height + self.bounds.height) / font.lineHeight

        var y: CGFloat = font.lineHeight + textContainerInset.top

        for _ in 0..<Int(nLines) {
            context.move(to: .init(x: 0.0, y: y))
            context.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: y))
            y += font.lineHeight
        }

        context.strokePath()
    }
    
}
```

You use it just like a normal `UITextView` as in this example view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let testTextView = LinedTextView()
        
        testTextView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        testTextView.text =  "When a user taps a text view, a keyboard appears; when a user taps Return in the keyboard, the keyboard disappears and the text view can handle the input in an application-specific way. You can specify attributes, such as font, color, and alignment, that apply to all text in a text view."
        
        testTextView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 28.0, weight: .regular)
        
        testTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testTextView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            testTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            testTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this when running:

[image]

Please note: this is ***Example Code Only!!!*** - it is intended to give you something to learn from and should not be considered "production ready."

Comment: This is the answer I was most looking for.Thanks for your cooperation.